# Getting name of all the exchange server within an organisation?

Tags: exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet, exchange-management-shell

I have using the exchange server 2013 , there are six exchange server in the organization. I wants to display the name of all the six exchange server in the organization using exchange management shell (cmdlets) . I am using get-exchangeServer cmdlet , but it display the name of  only one exchange server on which i am working. So, please tell me the cmdlets script which help me to display the name of all the exchange server in the organization

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for Get-ExchangeServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh528526.aspx) clearly specifies that you need to be assigned permissions before you can run this cmdlet. My guess is that you need the [OrganizationManagement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638114%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) permission to see all exchange servers from your AD.

Comment: How can i get the OrganizationManagement permission . Please help

Comment: You'll need to be added to an RBAC role that holds that permission by the Exchange administrator.